# mysql Insert query datatype

Tags: mysql

I have table product_type with columns: ID_TYPE, PRODUCT_NAME, DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY.

INSERT QUERY should be:

```
Insert into product_type(PRODUCT_NAME, DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY)
values
('Muffin','blahblahblah','1 piece'),
('Cookies','blahblahblah','1 kg');
```

`QUANTITY` column has datatype `DECIMAL`. And I have problem with inserting product quantity. I'we got error:

> 3 row(s) affected, 3 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column
>   'QUANTITY' at row 1 1265 Data truncated for column 'QUANTITY' at row
>   2: 2 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 2

Do you have any solution? Maybe I should write just 1 instead of '1 piece' or '1 kg'.

Comment: `"QUANTITY column has datatype DECIMAL"` - Well, "1 piece" isn't a decimal value.  It's a string.

Comment: In other words, store '1' and 'piece'/'kg' in separate columns

Comment: Thank you guys! This is my first db and i'm still making mistakes :) I made one more table Quantity with columns ID_QUANTITY and TYPE_QUANTITY. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you said if the data type of quantity is decimal then you cant store srting in it. for storing the units i would suggest you to make another column Unit of char type to store the units like Kg or Ltr or g etc.

```
ID_TYPE, PRODUCT_NAME, DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY.
INSERT QUERY should be:
Insert into product_type(PRODUCT_NAME, DESCRIPTION, QUANTITY, UNIT)
values
('Muffin','blahblahblah',1, 'piece'),
('Cookies','blahblahblah',1 ,'kg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the datatype of `QUANTITY` column, I think it is `INT` or `DECIMAL` and you are trying to insert a string value `1 piece` in it. In that case the integer past i.e. `1` is inserted with the message

> Data truncated for column 'QUANTITY' at row 1

So insert the appropriate value as per the `datatype`